# UITabBar does not animate properly when show/hide with notched devices e.g iPhone X

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitabbar

I am facing issue with notched devices e.g iPhone X with UITabBar control.
See below attachment, works well in iPhone 8.

[image]

See below is my code:

```
class TabVC: UIViewController  {
    @IBOutlet var tabBar: UITabBar!
    @IBOutlet var constraintBottomSpace: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
   func hide() {
        
        self.tabBar.alpha = 1
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
                self.constraintBottomSpace.constant = -50
                self.tabBar.alpha = 0
                self.view.layoutSubviews()
        })
    }
    
    func show() {
        self.tabBar.alpha = 0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
           self.tabBar.alpha = 1
            self.constraintBottomSpace.constant = 16
            self.view.layoutSubviews()
         })
    }
}
```

See below is my bottom constraints set with safe Area.Bottom for first item.

[image]

I triggered show and hide function on scrolling up and down events.

Comment: Looks like the inner buttons within the rounded rectangle, are shifting up when the animation starts. Might be caused by the safeareaInsets which values on notch devices is not zero compared to an iPhone8 for example . You may check the layout within the custom tab bar if any calculations is missing to consider the safe area insets

Comment: @LucaIaco I have also tried both way, bottom margin to superView and also bottom margin to safe view but its still having an issue.
If I not take UITabBar, and UIButtons each replaced with UITabBarButton, then its work well but having an issue with UITabBar with notched devices only